# rundeck - switch to root user in job script

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rundeck

Logging via terminal I can switch to root user fine:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-70:~$ sudo -s
root@ip-10-0-0-70:~# whoami
root
```

So I created in rundeck a job script with this:

```
whoami;
echo "1st step";
sudo -s;
echo "2nd step";
```

And when I run this, it prints:

```
ubuntu
1st step
```

After print '1st step' it get stucked forever. Seems a problem with `sudo -s` command.

- tried `sudo -i` but the same happens
- tried `sudo su - root` but the same happens
- rundeck is logging as ubuntu user, me too

any idea to switch to root in rundeck script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.
You are running a shell via 'sudo -s' and then not leaving/exiting it ! So it waits forever for somethig that won't come.

You can probably add 'sudo' as an Advanced option of your script (where it says "Run script with an interpreter or prefix. E.g.: sudo, time:").
But it will run your whole script as root.
If you just want a specific command to be run as root , just prefix your command with sudo as so:

```
sudo "enter_your_command_to_be_run_as_root_here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Entering the command prefixed by Sudo will generate the following error on most linux distributions.

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

You can enable sudo without tty by running 'visudo' and commenting out the defaults line or removing 'requiretty' from the defaults line.

Details can be found here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-sudo-sorry-you-must-haveattytorun/